# How to compute all trigrams of a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to compute and count all trigrams of a string in SQL Server.

For example if the string is `hello` I want the following output:

```
Trigram Count
------- -----
hel     1
ell     1
llo     1
lo-     1
```

[Wikipedia page on n-gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)

Comment: Please give sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what an n-gram is but based on Ed's answer is this what you need?

```
declare @string varchar(max) = 'hello'
declare @n int = 3

set @string = @string + REPLICATE('-',@n - (len(@string) % @n))

;with n as
(
SELECT 1 AS i
UNION ALL
SELECT i+1 
FROM n
WHERE i <= (LEN(@string)-@n)
)
select SUBSTRING(@string, i, @n), COUNT(*)
from n
group by  SUBSTRING(@string, i, @n)
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: lo- must be part of the output

Comment: My question was "why is it"? i.e. can you do a better job of explaining it for people that don't know what trigrams are.

Comment: ... and for people that can't be bothered to read the Wikipedia article. Is Ed's interpretation correct?

Comment: From my reading, underscore equals a space character, so should not occur if there are no spaces in the input string. Replacing all spaces wirth an underscore in the input should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing from Ed and Martin, I think this is a correct implementation:

```
declare @string varchar(max) = 'here kitty kitty' 

SET @string = replace(@string, ' ', '-') --Wikipedia says this should be underscore, not dash
;with n as 
( 
    SELECT 1 AS i 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i + 1  
    FROM n 
    WHERE i < (LEN(@string)-2) 
) 
select SUBSTRING(@string, i, 3) AS Trigram, COUNT(*) AS Count 
from n 
group by SUBSTRING(@string, i, 3) 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: I've no idea whether or not that is correct but +1. Did you read the Wikipedia article? Edit: I see that you did!

Comment: I read the concise trigram page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram). This algorithm gives the same output as that page.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Martin Smith's answer - added logic to pad the string out with `-` to a number of characters divisible by 3

```
declare @string varchar(max) = 'hello'

SET @string = (SELECT CASE LEN(@string) % 3
                          WHEN 1 THEN @string + '--'
                          WHEN 2 THEN @string + '-'
                          ELSE @string
                      END )
;with n as
(
SELECT 1 AS i
UNION ALL
SELECT i+1 
FROM n
WHERE i < (LEN(@string)-2)
)
select SUBSTRING(@string, i, 3) AS Trigram, COUNT(*) AS Count
from n
group by  SUBSTRING(@string, i, 3)
option (maxrecursion 0)
```