# Generating an n-gram table with an SQL query

Tags: sql, search, nlp, n-gram

I'm trying to implement a fuzzy search with JavaScript client side, to search a largish db (300 items roughly) of records contained in an SQL database. My constraint is that it is not possible to perform a live query on the database- I must generate "indexes" as flat files during a nightly batch job. And so, starting with a db that looks like this:

```
ID.    NAME
1.       The Rain Man
2.       The Electric Slide
3.       Transformers
```

I need to create within a single query something like this:

```
Trigram   ID
the        1
the        2
he_        1
he_        2
e_r        1
_ra        1
rai        1
ain        1
in_        1
n_m        1
_ma        1
man        1
e_e        2
_el        2
ele        2
lec        2
```

Etc etc, typos not withstanding. The rules here are that ''n' is the length of the strings in the first column, that only a-z and _ are valid characters, any other character being normalized to Lower case, or mapped to _, that a group by n-gram clause may be applied to the table.  Thus, I would hope to gain a table that would allow me to quickly look up a particular n-gram and get a list of all the Ids of rows which contain that sequence.  I'm not a clever enough SQL cookie to figure this problem out. Can you?

Comment: What version of SQL?  I think this would be better implemented outside of SQL however

Comment: I don't know which version. All I know is that I've got a field that takes SQL in an asp application. You may shudder at will

Comment: Are you going to write the BATCH process in ASP?  Without knowing the version of SQL, it would be tough to have a SQL query generate a flat file...

Comment: Don't worry about the io /batch stuff. I'm just interested in formulating the query part.

Comment: SQL is not very strong at the type of string manipulation you are describing.  It might be a possible with some sort of recursive query or a CTE (MS-SQL), but without knowing the back end SQL version, it would be very difficult to write the query.   Sorry

Comment: Let me put it this way: is it possible to generate every combination of three letters with a select statement?

Comment: If you're using MS SQL Server, this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832241/how-to-compute-all-trigrams-of-a-string-in-sql-server/3832517#3832517 - this logic could be wrapped in a function to generate the n-grams.

Comment: "to search a largish db (300 items roughly)" .. that's nothing really :)

Comment: i mean largish in the sense that i might not want to send it to the client on every page visit.

Answer (score 6):

I created an T-SQL NGrams that works quite nicely; note the comments section for examples of how to use

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.nGrams8K
(   
    @string VARCHAR(8000),
    @n TINYINT,
    @pad BIT
)
/*
Created by: Alan Burstein
Created on: 3/10/2014
Updated on: 5/20/2014   changed the logic to use an "inline tally table"
            9/10/2014   Added some more code examples in the comment section
            9/30/2014   Added more code examples
            10/27/2014  Small bug fix regarding padding

Use:    Outputs a stream of tokens based on an input string.
        Works just like mdq.nGrams; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487027(v=sql.105).aspx. 

n-gram defined:
    In the fields of computational linguistics and probability, 
    an n-gram is a contiguous sequence of n items from a given 
    sequence of text or speech. The items can be phonemes, syllables,
    letters, words or base pairs according to the application.

    To better understand N-Grams see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram
*/
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS

RETURN
    WITH
    E1(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(n)),
    E2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
    iTally(n) AS 
    (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@string)+@n) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b
    ),
    NewString(NewString) AS 
    (   
        SELECT  REPLICATE(CASE @pad WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE ' ' END,@n-1)+@string+
                REPLICATE(CASE @pad WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE ' ' END,@n-1)
    )
    SELECT TOP ((@n)+LEN(@string))
            n AS [sequence], 
            SUBSTRING(NewString,n,@n) AS token
    FROM iTally
    CROSS APPLY NewString
    WHERE n < ((@n)+LEN(@string));

/*
------------------------------------------------------------
-- (1) Basic Use
-------------------------------------------------------------

;-- (A)basic "string to table":
SELECT [sequence], token
FROM dbo.nGrams8K('abcdefg',1,1);

-- (b) create "bi-grams" (pad bit off)
SELECT [sequence], token
FROM dbo.nGrams8K('abcdefg',2,0);

-- (c) create "tri-grams" (pad bit on)
SELECT [sequence], token
FROM dbo.nGrams8K('abcdefg',3,1);

-- (d) filter for only "tri-grams"
SELECT [sequence], token
FROM dbo.nGrams8K('abcdefg',3,1)
WHERE len(ltrim(token)) = 3;

-- note the query plan for each. The power is coming from an index
-- also note how many rows are produced: len(@string+(@n-1))
-- lastly, you can trim as needed when padding=1

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (2) With a variable
------------------------------------------------------------

-- note, in this example I am getting only the stuff that has three letters
DECLARE @string varchar(20) = 'abcdefg',
        @tokenLen tinyint = 3;

SELECT [sequence], token
FROM dbo.nGrams8K('abcdefg',3,1)
WHERE len(ltrim(token)) = 3;
GO

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (3) An on-the-fly alphabet (this will come in handy in a moment)
------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @alphabet VARCHAR(26)='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

SELECT [sequence], token
FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@alphabet,1,0);
GO

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (4) Character Count
------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)='The quick green fox jumps over the lazy dog and the lazy dog just laid there.',

@alphabet VARCHAR(26)='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

SELECT a.token, COUNT(b.token) ttl
FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@alphabet,1,0) a
LEFT JOIN dbo.nGrams8K(@string,1,0) b ON a.token=b.token
GROUP BY a.token
ORDER BY a.token;
GO

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (5) Locate the start position of a search pattern
------------------------------------------------------------
;-- (A) note these queries:
    DECLARE @string varchar(100)='THE QUICK Green FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOGS BACK';
    -- (i)
        SELECT  * FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string,1,0) a;
    -- (ii) note this query:
        SELECT  * FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string,1,0) a WHERE [token]=' ';

-- (B) and now the word count (@string included for presentation)
    SELECT  @string AS string, 
            count(*)+1 AS words
    FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string,1,0) a
    WHERE [token]=' '
    GO 

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (6) search for the number of occurances of a word
------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)='The quick green fox jumps over the lazy dog and the lazy dog just laid there.',
        @alphabet VARCHAR(26)='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        @searchString VARCHAR(100)='The';

-- (5a) by location
SELECT  sequence-(LEN(@searchstring)) AS location, 
        token AS searchString
FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string,LEN(@searchstring+' ')+1,0) b
WHERE token=@searchString;

-- (2b) get total
SELECT  @string AS string, 
        @searchString AS searchString, 
        COUNT(*) AS ttl
FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string,LEN(@searchstring+' ')+1,0) b
WHERE token=@searchString;

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (7) Special SubstringBefore and SubstringAfter
------------------------------------------------------------

-- (7a) SubstringBeforeSSI (note: SSI = substringIndex)
    ALTER FUNCTION dbo.SubstringBeforeSSI
    (
        @string varchar(1000),
        @substring varchar(100),
        @substring_index tinyint
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    RETURN
        WITH get_pos AS
        (
            SELECT rn = row_number() over (order by sequence), substring_index = sequence
            FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string,len(@substring),1)
            WHERE token=@substring
        )
        SELECT newstring = substring(@string,1,substring_index-len(@substring))
        FROM get_pos
        WHERE rn=@substring_index;
    GO

    DECLARE @string varchar(1000)='10.0.1600.22',
            @searchPattern varchar(100)='.',
            @substring_index tinyint = 3;

    SELECT * FROM dbo.SubstringBeforeSSI(@string,@searchPattern,@substring_index);
    GO

-- (7b) SubstringBeforeSSI (note: SSI = substringIndex)
    ALTER FUNCTION dbo.SubstringAfterSSI
    (
        @string varchar(1000),
        @substring varchar(100),
        @substring_index tinyint
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    RETURN
        WITH get_pos AS
        (
            SELECT rn = row_number() over (order by sequence), substring_index = sequence
            FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string,len(@substring),1)
            WHERE token=@substring
        )
        SELECT newstring = substring(@string,substring_index+1,8000)
        FROM get_pos
        WHERE rn=@substring_index;
    GO

    DECLARE @string varchar(1000)='<notes id="1">blah, blah, blah</notes><notes id="2">More Notes</notes>',
    @searchPattern varchar(100)='</notes>',
    @substring_index tinyint = 1;

    SELECT @string, *
    FROM dbo.SubstringAfterSSI(@string,@searchPattern,@substring_index);

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (8) Strip non-numeric characters from a string
------------------------------------------------------------

-- (8a) create the function
ALTER FUNCTION StripNonNumeric_itvf(@OriginalText VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS TABLE 
--WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
return
    WITH ngrams AS 
    (
        SELECT  n = [sequence], c = token            
        FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@OriginalText,1,1)
    ),
    clean_txt(CleanedText) AS
    (
        SELECT c+''
        FROM ngrams
        WHERE ascii(substring(@OriginalText,n,1)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    SELECT CleanedText
    FROM clean_txt;
GO

-- (8b) use against a value or variable
SELECT CleanedText
FROM dbo.StripNonNumeric_itvf('value123');

-- (8c) use against a table

-- test harness:
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#strings') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #strings;

WITH strings AS
(
    SELECT TOP (100000) string = newid()
    FROM sys.all_columns a CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns b
)
SELECT * 
INTO #strings
FROM strings;
GO

-- query (returns 100K rows every 3 seconds on my pc):
SELECT CleanedText 
FROM #strings
CROSS APPLY dbo.StripNonNumeric_itvf(string);

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (9) A couple complex String Algorithms 
------------------------------------------------------------

-- (9a) hamming distance between two strings:
DECLARE @string1 varchar(8000) = 'xxxxyyyzzz',
        @string2 varchar(8000) = 'xxxxyyzzzz';


    SELECT  string1 = @string1,
            string2 = @string2,
            hamming_distance = count(*)
    FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string1,1,0) s1
    CROSS APPLY dbo.nGrams8K(@string2,1,0) s2
    WHERE s1.sequence = s2.sequence
    AND s1.token <> s2.token
GO

-- (9b) inner join between 2 strings 
    --(can be used to speed up other string metrics such as the longest common subsequence)
DECLARE @string1 varchar(100)='xxxx123yyyy456zzzz',
        @string2 varchar(100)='xx789yy000zz';

WITH 
    s1(string1) AS
    (   
        SELECT [token]+''
        FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string1,1,0)
        WHERE charindex([token],@string2)<>0
        ORDER BY [sequence]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
    s2(string2) AS
    (   
        SELECT [token]+''
        FROM dbo.nGrams8K(@string2,1,0)
        WHERE charindex([token],@string1)<>0
        ORDER BY [sequence]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    SELECT string1, string2
    FROM s1 
    CROSS APPLY s2;

------------------------------------------------------------
-- (10) Advanced Substring Metrics
------------------------------------------------------------

-- (10a) Identify common substrings and their location

DECLARE @string1 varchar(100) = 'xxx yyy zzz', 
        @string2 varchar(100) = 'xx yyy zz';

-- (i) review the two strings
SELECT  str1 = @string1,
        str2 = @string2;

-- (ii) the results
WITH 
iTally AS
(
    SELECT n 
    FROM dbo.tally t
    WHERE n<= len(@string1)
),
distinct_tokens AS
(
    SELECT ng1 = ng1.token, ng2 = ng2.token --= ltrim(ng1.token), ng2 = ltrim(ng2.token)
    FROM itally
    CROSS APPLY dbo.nGrams8K(@string1,n,1) ng1
    CROSS APPLY dbo.nGrams8K(@string2,n,1) ng2
    WHERE ng1.token=ng2.token
)
SELECT  ss_txt = ng1, 
        ss_len = len(ng1),
        str1_loc = charindex(ng1,@string1),
        str2_loc = charindex(ng2,@string2)
FROM distinct_tokens
WHERE ng1<>'' AND charindex(ng1,@string1)+charindex(ng2,@string2)<>0
GROUP BY ng1, ng2
ORDER BY charindex(ng1,@string1), charindex(ng2,@string2), len(ng1);

-- (10b) Longest common substring function

-- (i) function
    IF EXISTS
    (   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
        WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'lcss')
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.lcss;
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.lcss(@string1 varchar(100), @string2 varchar(100))
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN
        SELECT TOP (1) with ties token
        FROM dbo.tally
        CROSS APPLY dbo.nGrams8K(@string1,n,1)
        WHERE n <= len(@string1)
        AND charindex(token, @string2) > 0
        ORDER BY len(token) DESC;
    GO

-- (ii) example of use
    DECLARE @string1 varchar(100) = '000xxxyyyzzz',
            @string2 varchar(100) = '999xxyyyzaa';

    SELECT  string1 = @string1, 
            string2 = @string2,
            token
    FROM dbo.lcss(@string1, @string2);
*/
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to repeat this statement:

```
insert into trigram_table ( Trigram, ID )
select substr( translate( lower( Name ), ' ', '_' ), :X, :N ),
       ID
  from db_table
```

for all :X from 1 to Len(Name) + 1 - :N

You will also have to extend the translate function for all the other special characters you'd want to convert to an underscore.  Right now it's just translating a blank into an underscore.

For performance you could do the translate and lower functions on the Trigram column in a last pass on the trigram_table so you're not doing those functions for each :X.